# Why is a countable set closed?

Tags: general-topology

If $T$ is an uncountable set, show that $$\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,T,\text{ all sets whose complements is at most countable}\}$$ forms a topology on $T$.

Answer:

We have $∅$ and $T$ in T . To check the other two axioms, it is easier to work with
complements, i.e. at most countable sets, and show that they satisfy the ‘closed set’ axioms:
finite unions are closed (**clear, since they are at most countable**), and arbitrary intersections
are closed (again, **they are at most countable, or empty**)

I don't exactly get the things in bold, in particular:

> Why is the finite union of at most countable sets closed? It is definitely not clear for me. Could somebody explain?

**In particular, why is an at most countable set closed?**

Comment: Easier to prove it as: the finite union of at most countable sets is at most countable.

Comment: and it's rather clear that the intersection of at most countable sets is at most countable

Comment: @GEdgar So a countable set is closed?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner So a countable set is closed? Is this some theorem or definition? I think I should reformulate my question

Comment: For topology you have to prove given set is closed w.r.t finite intersections and closed w.r.t arbitrary unions

Comment: the topology is defined to have all sets whose complements are at most countable open, and the complements of sets in a topology are closed, so, yes, all at most countable sets are closed in this topology

Comment: this is the [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What do you mean by "open" and "closed" in the first place?

In topology there is no such thing as an "open set" or "closed set" as such. Rather, there are many different notions of "open-ness" and "closed-ness" depending on which **topology** we're looking at. The more precise statement here is:

> Every at-most-countable set is closed *in the sense of $\mathcal{T}$*,

but the "in the sense of $\mathcal{T}$"-bit is often dropped when there is only one topology being considered.

Remember that the closed sets are **by definition** the complements of the open sets. The open sets, in turn, are exactly the elements of the topology $\mathcal{T}$ - again by definition: "open set in the sense of $\mathcal{T}$" just means "element of $\mathcal{T}$."

In this case, all sets with at-most-countable complements are open in the sense of $\mathcal{T}$; this is what the definition of $\mathcal{T}$ explicitly says *(incidentally, note that including $T$ in $\mathcal{T}$ is redundant since $T\setminus T$ is already at most countable)*. Consequently, all at-most-countable sets are closed in the sense of $\mathcal{T}$. *(And so since the union of finitely many countable sets is countable, we have that $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under finite intersections as desired.)*

Comment: I see, so I had this fundamental mistake of thinking that the sets are open in some topology meaning that they have to be open in some set like $\Bbb R$ (or some other set). I would like to clarify if my thinking is right:

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ be a set with topology $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{X\}\}$ 

So, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are open in the topological space ($X,\mathcal{T}$), since we defined it so? 

But in the normal sense, a set containing a number will not be open.

Even if I let $X=\Bbb R$, with the same topology, the sets $\{1\},\{2\}$ will be open?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Well, that $\mathcal{T}$ *isn't* actually a topology since it's not closed under union: $\{1\}\cup\{2\}\not\in\mathcal{T}$. However, ignoring that issue yes, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ would be open in that topology by definition. And yes, taking $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\},\mathbb{R}\}$ would give us a topological space in which (for example) $\{1\}$ is open but $(3,4)$ is *not* open.